# StackExchange Redis SortedSetRangeByScoreWithScoresAsync Get Top n Elements

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm using StackExchange.Redis API in a .NET application for analytics.

I'm using Sorted Sets as datastore. What is the equivalent method in StackExchange.Redis for below redis Command:

```
ZREVRANGEBYSCORE "KEY:2014052923" +inf -inf withscores Limit 0 10
```

What is the equivalent way in StackExchange.Redis API using SortedSetRangeByScoreWithScoresAsync function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SortedSetEntry[] values = db.SortedSetRangeByScoreWithScores(
    "KEY:2014052923", order: Order.Descending, take: 10);
```

or the `*Async` twin:

```
SortedSetEntry[] values = await db.SortedSetRangeByScoreWithScoresAsync(
    "KEY:2014052923", order: Order.Descending, take: 10);
```

Note the additional parameters for `start`, `stop`, `exclude` and `skip` that I haven't specified because they have appropriate values already. In case it isn't clear, `exclude` is related to the `(` prefix on ranges, as described on [`ZRANGEBYSCORE`](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore).

Comment: Sample, just to sanity-check that I haven't messed up horribly: http://pastie.org/9238570

Comment: Thanks Marc, that works perfectly as per my requirement.